# Rust: check if two elements in a Vec meet a condition

Tags: rust

Given a `Vec<isize>` like so:

```
let input = "12
  122
  100
  4444
  34
  3
  66
  78
  9";

let contents = input.lines()
    .map(|l| l.parse().unwrap())
    .collect();
```

I want to determine whether `contents` contains `2` `isize`s which add up to `300`, I would think the function should go something like this.

```
fn check_for_factors(contents: Vec<isize>, target: isize) -> bool {
    contents
        .into_iter()
        .any(|&x| x + contents[0..n] == target) // or however to loop here
}

check_for_factors(contents, 300);
```

Thing is, I'm not sure how to loop though `contents` in the `any` block. Is this solution viable? How do I loop though `contents` inside final line?

Comment: iter twice, don't use into_iter

Comment: So `iter().iter()`? Or `... .any(|&x| x + contents.iter() == target)`?

Comment: The latter: In the closure passed to `any`, use `contents.iter()` to iterate over contents again. You have to use `iter` to generate the initial iterator as well because `into_iter` consumes the `contents` vector, rendering it inaccessible in the `any` closure.

Comment: You don't need a nested loop here. This can be done in linear time by using a `HashSet`, iterating over it, and checking whether `300 - x` is in the set for all `x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, do it the dumb, obvious way.

```rust
fn check_for_factors(contents: &[isize], target: isize) -> bool {
    for (i, x) in contents.iter().enumerate() {
        for y in contents.iter().skip(i) {
            if x + y == target {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    false
}
```

P.S. I've changed the signature to `&[isize]` because this function does not need to take ownership of the Vec.

Comment: I like this more because this doesn't have the same-element problem, this only traverses the "remaining" elements (the other approach compares each pair TWICE actually, since it starts from the beginning each time), and this obeys the KISS principal.

Comment: I'm going to accept this one since it's most efficient and doesn't rely on external crates. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Using the `combinations` adapter can make life easier and increase the code readability.

```
fn check_for_factors(contents: &[isize], target: isize) -> bool {
    contents.iter().combinations(2).any(|x| x[0] + x[1] == target)
}
```

[Playgound](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a1c4ac541275d1e01b304f6dda03415d)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with iterators that avoids checking the same pair twice:

```
fn check_for_factors(contents: &[isize], target: isize) -> bool {
    contents.iter().enumerate().any(|(i, &x)| {
        contents
            .iter()
            .skip(i+1)
            .any(|&y| x + y == target)
    })
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5cd1587b67b503d414b61e2b8a899371)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Stargateur and @EvilTak I figured it out.

```
fn check_for_factors(contents: Vec<isize>, target: isize) -> bool {
    contents
        .iter()
        .any(|&x| contents.iter().any(|&y| x + y == target));
}
```

Pretty simple really (now).

**Update** based on @EvilTrak's help.

```
fn check_for_factors(contents: Vec<isize>, target: isize) -> bool {
    contents.iter().enumerate().any(|(i, &x)| {
        contents
            .iter()
            .enumerate()
            .filter(|&(j, _)| i != j)
            .any(|(_, &y)| x + y == target)
    })
}
```

Comment: This may not be relevant for your problem, but `x` and `y` can be the same element in your algorithm. If `target` is twice any element in `contents` (but not the sum of any pair of elements), then the function will return true, which may not be what you want. E.g. `check_for_factors(vec![1, 2, 3], 6)` returns true.

Comment: You beat me to my next problem! I figure I can throw some kind of index on both and skip if they're equal somehow?